# how to update an app when ng cli and angular change version best practice

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to update an app when ng cli and angular change version like now with ng cli 1.5 and angular 5 ?

My goal is to have an existing project with for instance angular 4 and ng cli 1.4,updated to angular 5 and the one scaffold built by ng cli.
(I don't know in this case but also the scaffold have sometime changed so I want the brand new scaffold)

An alternative should be using meld.

I'm looking for a best way/practice because right now I'm following all of these steps.

By now I update if possible the node version with nvm so for instance

- `nvm install v9.0.0`
- `nvm use v9.0.0`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- `ng new myproject`
- overwrite the src and assets folders
- update `package.json`
- copy files like `.stylelintrc`
- delete `package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

As you can see a lot of work and also error prone so I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to do the update.

### UPDATE

The really problems are the external lib
for instance for the OpaqueToken :(

Comment: What possessed you to format it like that?

Comment: you right thx for the new format far better :D